# VBA application.index Array() in rows doesn't work

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to use the Application.Index function in excel VBA.

I currently have an array(4,11139) that I am trying to splice into two separate arrays one containing the first 2 rows (2,11139) and the other containing the 3rd/4th rows (2, 11139). Various searches have suggested this code is the correct method but it's not working properly: (I've condensed the code to what is relevant)

```
Dim Adjusted_Data_Array() As Single
Dim Final_Data_Array() As Variant
Dim Sys1_Data_Array() As Variant
Dim Sys2_Data_Array() As Variant
'Function that creates a 4,11139 variant array
Final_Data_Array = Strip_Erroneous(Adjusted_Data_Array, 1)
'Splice first two rows
Sys1_Data_Array = Application.Index(Final_Data_Array, Array(1, 2), 0)
'splice 3/4th rows
Sys2_Data_Array = Application.Index(Final_Data_Array, Array(3, 4), 0)
```

So I should now have 2 arrays each containing half the data from the first array. But all I get in the new arrays is a one dimensional array with two rows. Like this:

#### Screenshot of the watches from the 3 arrays discussed above.

[image: Screenshot of the watches from the 3 arrays discussed above.]

I've tried it with the Array(1,2) in the columns and that doesn't work either.

I can solve the issue in this regard by simply splitting into 4 separate one dimensional arrays (that works fine, it's the Array(1,2) or Array(3,4) that doesn't seem to. But I know in a future work coming up I'll be needing to splice much bigger arrays so would like to understand why it's not working ready for that.
Big thanks in advance.

Edit:
Tried using:

```
Sys1_Data_Array = Application.Index(Final_Data_Array, Application.Transpose(Array(1, 2)), 0)
```

as per charles suggestion below but end up with the array's simply switched indices as shown:

#### Screenshot of watches from transpose(array(1,2) attempt

[image: Screenshot of watches from transpose(array(1,2) attempt]

Comment: I do not believe the `INDEX` function can accept an array as an argument for `row_num` or `column_num`. If one of them is zero; the other has to point to a single row/column.

Comment: Thanks Ron I was starting to wonder that, I'm not sure how to explain this though: https://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/vba-trick-of-the-week-slicing-an-array-without-loop-application-index/ then, and there are many more examples out there of people instructing others to use it in that form.

Comment: In the comments are a number of users who were unable to get the example in the article to work, when using an array argument for `row_num`.  Also note that if you use the fully qualified `application.worksheetfunction.index...` you will get a type mis-match when you use the `Array(1,2)` argument.

Comment: In any event, its probably more efficient to do this using VBA array loops which would only require one copy operation rather than passing a copy of the array to Index and then Index passing a subset copy back.

Comment: as a side note, the most efficient is to not copy the array at all and just use  values in the original array. Index can't be used to return more than one row/column AFAIK

Comment: So if I wanted to paste columns 3 & 4 from my array into a worksheet range, could I do this without looping or Indexing?

Comment: @MattCarter you can fill the 2 columns separately with 2 Index calls, or better just use 2 separate array(2,11139) instead of one array(4,11139)

Comment: Cheers @Slai, that's a no then. It's my own fault for changing my spreadsheet format after writing the code but having already written a few thousand lines of code to get to the Array in question and now wanting to paste the two sets of columns separately I don't really want to go back through a long way to split the arrays earlier. Therefore I think I'll be doing the 2 Index calls in this instance as I shouldn't have more than 20,000 rows and never more than 4 columns to deal with so it's pretty quick really. Then I'll write a function for future work. Cheers for all your ideas :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the INDEX approach if you wrap the ARRAY inside a TRANSPOSE

```
var1 = Application.Index(varData, Application.Transpose(Array(1, 2)), 0)
var2 = Application.Index(varData, Application.Transpose(Array(3, 4)), 0)
```

Apologies: actually this does not work!
But its about 2.5 times slower than just copying the relevant parts of the array using VBA.

```
For k = 1 To UBound(varData, 2)
    For j = 1 To 2
        var1(j, k) = varData(j, k)
        var2(j, k) = varData(j + 2, k)
    Next 
Next
```

Comment: Thanks Charles, still not working properly though. I now have a 2,1 array rather than the 1,2 that was there before. Edited original post above to show it. Looks like I'm writing a function with loops to do it so my code stays nice and neat.

Answer (score 1):

```
TheAddress = "row(1:2)"
TheRows = Application.Evaluate(TheAddress) 'must be a 2 dimensions array 
TheColumns = Array(1, 2, 3)'must be a 1 dimension array 
Sys1_Data_Array = Application.Index(Final_Data_Array, TheRows, TheColumns) 
Cells(9, 1).Resize(UBound(Sys1_Data_Array), UBound(Sys1_Data_Array, 2)) = Sys1_Data_Array
```